# SQL Query to get most frequently visited place Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I developed project at **Laravel 5.2**. I have database structure like this :

user_visited

```
id | user_id | latitude     | longitude
01 | 1       | 140.5938388  | 36.3335513
02 | 1       | 140.2631739  | 36.3724621
03 | 1       | 140.0804782  | 36.083233
04 | 1       | 140.0855777  | 36.1048973
05 | 1       | 140.2215081  | 35.981243
06 | 1       | 140.577927   | 36.3114456
07 | 1       | 140.65826    | 36.6068145
08 | 1       | 140.109301   | 36.0865606
09 | 1       | 140.2055252  | 35.926693
10 | 1       | 139.7540075  | 36.1662458
11 | 1       | 140.2637594  | 36.241148
12 | 1       | 139.8043185  | 36.1115211
13 | 1       | 140.2183821  | 36.0601167
14 | 1       | 139.7540075  | 36.1662458
15 | 1       | 140.0309725  | 36.0381176
```

lcoations

```
id | Location name  | Type       | Address  | Latitude    | Longitude
31 | Murse Park     | Theme Park | 552-18   | 140.6066128 | 36.3985857
32 | Dom Park       | Theme Park | 552-12   | 140.6417064 | 36.5436575
33 | Football Park  | Theme Park | 588-1    | 140.3690094 | 36.4195418
34 | Istanbul Park  | Theme Park | 37       | 140.3330587 | 36.5449685
```

This is user's location history that get from mobile app that get location information every `n` seconds.

And from user's visited location history I want to know which place that users most frequently visited. How to do that?

The fact is, user can visit same location, but the longitude and latitude isn't perfect same.

Maybe we must set radius for 500 mill or what?

How to query that?

Comment: Can you please share few sample data for the lat and long?

Comment: What you try so far ?

Comment: @Arulkumar, i add some sample data for one user, places that user 1 has visited..

Comment: @Sami i don't know what query must i use, i just find query with asoc, but it's only get nearest place from where i exsists.

Comment: @YudiYohanesSeptianGotama is there any name associated with the locations ? I mean these locations must be representing some specific places right? Among which you want to show most visited.

Comment: @jaysingkar i updated my question, there is locations table

Answer (score 0):

answering so that someone might get help.
According to Geo location, we can consider a place same if its latitude and longitude are similar at 5 to 6 precision.
Let's say if lat and long of a place are (140.5938388,36.3335513) and a user visits a place with lat and long (140.59383723,36.33355213) then by querying with precision of 5 i.e (140.59383,36.33355) we get the same block where your location exists and taking count of those places/locations will give you the frequently visited places.

Edited:

```
SELECT count(location_name) FROM locations
LEFT JOIN user_visited ON TRUNCATE(user_visited.latitude,5) = TRUNCATE(locations.latitude,5) AND TRUNCATE(user_visited.longitude,5) = TRUNCATE(locations.longitude,5)
WHERE user_visited.user_id = 1
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @DanielM the problem is Yudi is unable to get the most visited places but due to small variation in lat, long its tough for him to get the most visited places. So I just gave an idea what I've done to get the same thing.

Comment: Thank you @DanielM for appreciation.